# Get values of specific elements present in the innerHTML of a 3rd party control using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have included a 3rd party (Dom non editable) control on my page, the inner html of which reads:

```
"<table >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td >
              <input id="ctl00$main$TimeSelector_txtHour" value="09">
               </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>"
```

I know I can substring the hell out of this string to read the value, wanted to know if there's a neater way to do this? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If that is the entirety of the innerHTML of an element, you can just do a `find('input')` on it.  `something.innerHTML` => `$(something).find('input')`

Comment: Actually it had more than one input field but thanks to your answer I was able to work that out. If you can put the above as a comment I will mark it as an answer, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question states that the string you provided in your OP is from an innerHTML.  So I am assuming you did something like the following to get that.

```
something.innerHTML
```

Since there is only a single input element in the html, you should be able to select the child just by its tag name, without having to worry about trying to figure out what its id is.  From that point, you would just need to call `val()` to get the value.

```
$(something).find('input').val()
```